# Is this sentence in a different language or is it just gibberish?

Tags: meaning, parsing

There's a line in the [lyrics for the song "Viva La Viva" by Stereopony](http://en.verygooddays.com/stereopony/lyrics/viva-la-viva-la/) that's written like this:

> ヨボセヨペゴパヨ チキンピリョヘヨ

Underneath this is:

> (わたしはチキンが大好きです。)

The second line isn't actually sung, so I'm assuming it's some kind of translation of the first. As for the first line, I've no idea where to even begin parsing this (besides the word チキン). Does it actually mean anything?

My first thought is that it's either a completely different language or that it's some kind of "language game" similar to Pig Latin in English. Or it could just be nonsense words used to fit in with the song (the "translation" line merely there for a joke).

Comment: It's in Korean. It says "Hello! I'm hungry. chicken" [and then I can't read the last part]

Comment: I think it says "Hello, I am hungry and I need/want chicken." in katakanized Korean. I could be wrong, though, since Korean is only my 7th language.  I do know for sure that it does not mean わたしはチキンが大好きです.

Comment: @非回答者 I had a sneaking suspicion it was Korean, despite not knowing any myself - that's one of the more popular foreign languages in Japan, isn't it?

Comment: @virmaior The last part is 필요해요, a conjugation of 필요하다. 필요 is of course cognate with Japanese hituyoo, both deriving from Chinese 必要.

Comment: Korean is as with 非回答者 my 7th too (in order of when I first learned a bit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Korean:

```
　ヨボセヨ　　　여보세요　　yeoboseyo　 　'Hello' (polite)
　ペゴパヨ　　　배고파요　　baegopayo　 　'[I'm] hungry' (polite)  
　チキン　　　　치킨　　　　chikin　　  　'chicken'  
　ピリョヘヨ　　필요해요　　piryohaeyo　　'[I] need' (polite)
```

The third column is Revised Romanization.  The glosses on the right aren't supposed to be a perfect translation, just to give you a general idea of what it says.  (I've studied Korean too, but I'm not a very advanced student.)

*I'm posting this little Community Wiki answer since it was already answered in the comments.  If anyone would like to improve this answer, please feel free :-)*